# When Jenkins fetches from git origin, it gives error "cannot lock ref"

Tags: git, jenkins

Recently, when my Jenkins pipeline updates from my git repo, it gives the error `error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/nmb/pdf-signature': 'refs/remotes/origin/nmb' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/nmb/pdf-signature'`.

It looks to me as if at one time, my `origin` remote had a branch named `nmb`, and now it has a branch named `nmb/pdf-signature`. I suppose that my Jenkins workspace has the old `nmb` branch, so it can't fetch the new `nmb/pdf-signature branch`.

If that's so, the solution appears easy: I went to my workspace on the server and `rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/*` so that it would fetch everything anew. In fact, when I start a new container with the workspace mounted, I'm able to run `git fetch ...`, but when I run Jenkins again, it results in the **same error as before**.

Have you any idea how to set this aright?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the reference you have is in the packed references file and is getting rewritten into the `refs` directory by one of your processes.  The simplest way to solve this, regardless of the situation, is to use `git fetch --prune origin`.  This removes any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the origin, which should fix the problem unless you have a nonstandard Git server.

This will work better than deleting the references by hand (which you should avoid in general) because it will apply to all references, however they're stored.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was in the name of the ref: `nmb/pdf-signature`. Someone had previously pushed a branch named `nmb` to origin, so it was looking inside of the directory it had created for `nmb`.

If instead users had pushed branches named `nmb/...`, then the origin would have a directory named `nmb` with subdirectory for refs, but as it is, origin will work with any ref that follows the pattern `nmb/...`